# Feed Me feeds not running

Tags: plugin-feedme

We have 3 instances of Feed Me installed:

- Prod: PHP 7.4.33; Craft CMS 3.7.63; Feed Me 4.5.3
- Staging: PHP 8.1.17; Craft CMS 3.9.1; Feed Me 4.7
- Dev: PHP 7.4.33; Craft CMS 3.9.1; Feed Me 4.7

Prod works as expected. However, in Staging and Dev, when "Run Feed" is clicked, the confirmation message appears at the top of the page, "Feed processing started", but no process actually runs, and there is no logging. It seems to be failing silently.

I'm concerned about updating Prod before sorting out what might be going on in these lower environments. Any known issues or recommendations?

Comment: Whats happens if you try to reconfigure the feeds in DEV?
Maybe try the debug functionality to see what it outputs.
You can do this by clicking the gear icon for the feed and then click the debug button.

Comment: Triggering Debug mode for a feed does allow the feed to run as expected. I'm not finding documentation explaining the underlying mechanics of Debug mode, though.